# Server architecture for an Android multiplayer game

Tags: android, multiplayer

I am building a multiplayer game. It is a card game. I was wondering what technology or SDK would be the best to program the server architecture part.

I was thinking about Node.js. Has anyone experience with it? Any better alternatives?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can try with the skiller SDK:

http://skiller-games.com/Developers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Perroloco, as Perroloco said, you can try out our Skiller SDK. Just register to our developer program, get application credentials, download the SDK and you are ready to go. You will not need server, hosting or protocol development. Use multiplayer tools simply by calling createGame, makeMove and endGame APIs.

If you will have any questions or will need any help we will be happy to help you: developers@skiller-games.com.

All the best and good luck.